# Make :Q! have the same functionality as :q! in vim

Tags: vim

Sometimes in vim, I accidentally type :Q instead of :q in normal mode. To work around this, I've added this in my .vimrc:

```
command Q q
```

This works fine for :Q, but in case I type :Q!, vim responds with "No ! allowed". How do I make vim accept :Q! and interpret it as :q! ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
:command -bang Q quit<bang>
```

For more information, see [`:help :command-bang`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3acommand-bang).

Answer (score 7):

I prefer this for my commands

```
command! -bar -bang Q quit<bang>
```

- The bang on `:command!` will allow to re-source your vimrc without errors, see `:help E174`
- The `-bar` argument will allow to concatenate further commands with |, see `:help :command-bar`
- `<bang>` expands to ! if one is used, see `:help :command-bang`